# Как автоматически генерировать отчеты 1С?

Tags: 1с

Есть несколько отчетов в 1С. Как можно сделать так, чтобы они автоматически генерировались и сохранялись на рабочем столе?
Если полностью автоматически нельзя (например раз в час), то можно ли сделать так, чтобы несколько отчетов генерировались при нажатии на 1 кнопку?

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. Сохраните необходимый отчет/обработку как внешнюю обработку (либо создайте свою внешнюю обработку). Создайте ярлык запуска 1С в параметрах укажите свою внешнюю обработку; Во внешней обработке в событие ПриОткрытии() добавьте код формирующий отчет, и сохраняющий его в нужное место; Ярлык запускайте по расписанию в Планировщике задач (Шедулер)
2. Установите AutoIT - это скриптовый язык, способный запустить приложение (1С) и выполнять нажатие мыши в нужную область экрана; С помощбю таких кликов мышью - формируйте отчет и сохраняйте; Скрипт запускайте по расписанию в Планировщике или пропишите прямо в скрипте;
3. В конфигурации 1С создайте ФоновоеЗадание, это код формирующий отчет и сохраняющий его на диск; Добавьте ФоновоеЗадание в список Регламентных заданий в 1С, настройте расписание запуска; В этом случае отчет будет формироваться в фоне (без открытия окна программы 1С, - на СЕРВЕРЕ)